# Getting Java Version in bash script results are blank

Tags: bash

I've got a bash script that grabs a bunch of environment data, part of that grabs the JDK location on a Unix machine and then runs the version check. It works on some Machines but not others for some reason. However manually running the command by plugging in the location works without issue. I'm thinking there is some delay in the java command and the bash script doesn't wait for it?

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_51"

JDK_VERSION=$($JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version 2>&1 | grep 'version' | awk '{gsub(/\"/,""); print $3}' )
```

However if I manually run it from command line outside of the shell script it works.

```
/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -version 2>&1 | grep 'version' | awk '{gsub(/\"/,""); print $3}'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for such a behaviour is that the PATH environment variable is different in your shell and in the script. You use 'grep' and 'awk' without absolute paths (i.e. relying on the interpreter to resolve the location of these tools).

There are a couple options on how you can confirm whether the above is the case:

1. you can create a script like the following:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> echo "$PATH"
> ```

then chmod 0700 it, execute it, and the run the same 'echo "$PATH"' command from you shell session.  Compare the two resulting lines and it's likely you will see the difference.

2. you can find the absolute paths to grep and awk and update your script to use the absolute paths.  The downside is that the script will be less portable and won't work on systems where the location of these tools is different.

Comment: Hi Galaxy,

I tried Option, however the $PATH was the same on the 2 environments.

2. I'm not certain the issue is with grep and awk's absolute path. Because as I said, if I manually specify the JDK path instead of using $JAVA_HOME, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$(cmd)` is executing a command but you are not exporting `JAVA_HOME`.

A fix is

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_51"
```

Comment: Hi Mark,
I'm not actually using Environment Variables, the above is meant to be from inside the .sh, I just happened to use a naming convention that may be familiar to Environment Paths.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Every invocation of bash has an associated environment that contains variables. You define JAVA_HOME in the environment of one invocation of bash and attempt to use it in a different environment (that of the 2nd invocation of bash).

Comment: What I'm saying is that I don't define JAVA_HOME outside of the shell script. So whenever the shell script is ran regardless of environment I'm running it on, it will redefine JAVA_HOME as JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_51". So I wouldn't need have a line for "export JAVA_HOME", since the variable is only defined and used within the script. My wording may be confusing on the 2 different environments part. Basically 2 different machines running the same script and the results are different.

Comment: Mark, a nice catch, thank you.  I believe you pin-pointed it.  Somehow I missed that the original script was not exporting the variable but was using it in a sub-shell.